# Fix-it Insert "as! PFUserResultBlock"

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, uiviewcontroller

Can anyone say why this error is happened, When I press fix-it it's add  "as! PFUserResultBlock" if I press again fix-it she add again "as! PFUserResultBlock" ,thanks for attention)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error` is not `NSError?`, but `Error?`, after changing it everything should be OK.

You don't have to specify the type of arguments, just simply put `(user, error) in` instead of `(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in`